# Terraform filters to retrieve key value

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

From the block of Terraform code which is from a state file, I need to
write a filter criteria that points at"dev-devic-efs" and pull the value "arn:aws:kms:eu-east-1:144382646821:key/e1652537-a360-4086-813d-4fc6668425a6"
Any help on how to do this filter would be much appreciated. Thank you

```
enter code here

"efs_key": {
      "value": {
        "alias": {
          "1-efs": "arn:aws:kms:eu-east-1:144382646821:key/e1b7e7fd-5ec3-41ce-94a8-8d34d43164ca",
          "2-efs": "arn:aws:kms:eu-east-1:144382646821:key/2de9045a-96bc-4bc0-83ef-b420d9ff3dc1",
          "3-efs": "arn:aws:kms:eu-east-1:144382646821:key/e379f46e-a36d-47e8-9652-d40b00f385ba",
          "4-efs": "arn:aws:kms:eu-east-1:144382646821:key/69d0bd86-53ea-4a51-b4a0-76754c7ed8fd",
          "5-efs": "arn:aws:kms:eu-east-1:144382646821:key/dfc1ead3-1b72-4c01-bdf2-c624ee565fca",
          "dev-devic-efs": "arn:aws:kms:eu-east-1:144382646821:key/e1652537-a360-4086-813d-4fc6668425a6"
        }
      },
      "type": [
        "object",
        {
          "alias": [
            "object",
            {
              "1-efs": "string",
              "2-efs": "string",
              "3-efs": "string",
              "4-efs": "string",
              "5-efs": "string",
              "dev-devic-efs": "string"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Why access this from the state instead of the config?

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thank you for getting back, the way I understand is we are creating a state file and storing it in S3 bucket. So in our set up, I do not think I can not get the info I need from the config (which I think you mean the KMS?). Also I believe it is an access restriction we have in place which limits us to look up the state file.

Comment: What are you doing with the KMS key value? Why not use the `aws_kms_alias` or `aws_kms_key` data sources?

Comment: Thank yiou @ydaetskcoR When I do "aws kms list-aliases" below is what I see"

        `{
            "AliasName": "alias/terraform-tf-state",
            "AliasArn": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:373282891562:alias/terraform-tf-state",
            "TargetKeyId": "z231a3a1-d821-38s8-8292-4w8q004290c2"
        }`

Block of code in my original question is the content from the state file based on the alias name above.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the Terraform code where you create your EFS file system and KMS keys?

Answer (score 0):

The state snapshots Terraform stores in your configured state storage backend are primarily for its own consumption, rather than for external consumption. The value you shared here is using a special value encoding that retains the Terraform language type (nested objects) alongside the value, which Terraform uses to work around the fact that the Terraform Language type system is a superset of JSON's.

The way I would suggest to solve the underlying problem here is to explicitly publish this data to some location separate from the state snapshots of this configuration. For example, you could publish this information in JSON format directly into a separate S3 bucket/key designated for this purpose alone:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "example" {
  bucket = "example"
  key    = "efs_keys"

  content = jsonencode({
    alias = { for k, o in aws_kms_alias.efs : k => o.arn }
  })
}
```

The program you are writing to consume this data can then read the `efs_keys` object from the `example` bucket and get the data it needs directly, rather than having to first extract it from Terraform's internal state snapshot format.

---

With that said, you *can* potentially extract this from the state file, if you reverse-engineer the state file format. The `value` property of that compound object will match what `jsonencode` would've produced in my example above, so you can consume it in the same way once you've located it in the state snapshot.

The caveat here is that future versions of Terraform might change the details of this format in a way that affects your downstream program. This format doesn't change *frequently*, but the storage of output values has changed at least three times during Terraform's life in response to changes to how output values work in the Terraform language, so it may change again in the future for similar reasons. If so, you'll need to update the program that's consuming this data to support the new format as part of upgrading Terraform.